# How to implement autocomplete using spring data solr

Tags: spring, solr, spring-data-solr

I am using spring data solr for my application and trying to implement autocomplete feature.

```
@SolrDocument

public class UserEntity{

    @Field
    private String id;

    @Field
    private String fullName;

    @Field
    private Date dob;

    @Field
    private String address;

    @Field
    private String phoneNumber;

}
```

I managed to implement autocomplete for single fields by using spring data solr Criteria .
But this got drawback becuase this will return a list of UserEntities. I have to iterate the user list and get the names.

1 . Is there any way that I can get **only the matching Names** using spring data solr ?

2 . If I need to implement **autocomplete across multiple fields** (name and address together) is it possible to do it using spring data solr ?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the Solr Example [here](https://github.com/christophstrobl/spring-data-solr-showcase) using Factes for autocomplete.

You also may use a terms vector which requires you to use `SolrTemplate.execte(SolrCallback)`  to access native Solr API.